# "Because" with past perfect or past simple?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

This is from a newspaper:

> The real reason he was arrested was because he **smeared** poo all over the walls.

Shouldn't the past perfect be used:

> ... he was arrested because he **had smeared** poo all over the walls.

The smearing occurred before the arrest, a past event that precedes another past event, so why use the past simple?

Answer (score 3):

Your quote uses "*was*" twice - once to show that he *was* arrested, and again to show that the cited reason *was* in the past. There is nothing in this sentence to suggest that the incident came after the arrest. In fact, the use of "because" shows that the latter was the *cause* of the former.

Your re-write makes perfect sense too though.

Comment: @anouk They are both past events joined by the conjunction "because" which denotes that one is the cause of the other. The order of events is clear.

Comment: I thought the past perfect was used to express that something happened in the past ( the smearing) before something else ( the arrest) that happened in the past. So in your opinion both past perfect and past simple are possible in this case? –

Comment: I was taught that past simple is possible instead of past perfect with "after" and "before" . I didn't know this rule also applies to " because".

Comment: @anouk There's no such rule. The rule of thumb would be if the (intended) order of events is clear, the past perfect is optional.